# How can I implement the visitor patter with return type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, design-patterns

I want to implement the visitor pattern for one of my class without having to depend on the types that will implement the interface to visit them.

My solution was this:

```cpp
class model::VisitableNode {
public:
   template<class T>
   virtual T accept(NodeVisitor<T>);
}
```

But C++ says that it doesn't support template + virtual methods

Node in my application will have only one implementation but if I don't use a template return type my model class will depend on the toolkit that I'm using to create the graphic for my app.

Comment: The originally conceived Visitor Pattern is a rather bad pattern to use. Take a look at the reimagined version in [Modern C++ Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design). That will most likely work for your situation.

Comment: @RSahu I don't think this book, however excellent, tackles this problem. It has a templatized visitable class akin to that of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65286765/775806) but I don't think that's what people need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a visitor needs to return a value, it is normal to store the returned value in the visitor itself. Thus:

```
NodeVisitor<double> dv;
node->accept(dv);
double result = dv.result();
```

If you don't like the boilerplate, you can wrap it in a *non-virtual* member:

```
class model::VisitableNode {
public:
   template<class T>
   /* non-virtual */ T accept(NodeVisitor<T>& v) {
      do_accept(v);
      return v.result;
   }
   virtual void do_accept(NodeVisitorBase& v) = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not template the class itself?

```
template<class T>
class model::VisitableNode<T> {
public:
  
   virtual T accept(NodeVisitor<T>);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. OP most likely wants to apply different visitors returning different types to the same node.